# Cannot open Powershell from context menu

Tags: powershell, context-menu

When I open Powershell from shift-right click menu, I get an error dialog showing "Explorer.EXE: Application not found"
[Screenshot of the error dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwdzF.png)

This is on Windows 10

I recently installed Guitar Pro 8's soundbank, and I found other posts about it but no solution: https://www.reddit.com/r/GuitarPro/comments/10k1jdz/guitar_pro_8_corrupting_the_windows_registry/ https://www.reddit.com/r/GuitarPro/comments/16t2zhg/powershell_stopped_working_after_installing_sound/

I checked the registry values for the shortcut and the command key looks fine:

`powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'`

I've also made sure Powershell's folder is in my PATH.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Note that in the SuperUser answer, the absolute path path is used. BTW, an error in *any* line of PATH makes all *subsequent* items invalid.

Comment: Adding a new key using the absolute path seems to work. However I do notice the background of the Powershell is black and no longer blue (not a big deal). If anything, I am more interested in why the original command does not work. I asked my friend to check their registry value and it's the same as mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following solution fixed my issue.

Credits to u/Smoother101 on Reddit

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\powershell.exe]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
```

Save that code to a file and save it as PSFix.reg. Import it and things should start working again immediately. The GP8 install breaks something in the path that I couldn't isolate in the time I was looking at the issue but that resolves it.